# Double-Click not working 18.04 gnome-tweak-tool installed/area clicked

Tags: 18.04, mouse, gnome-tweak-tool

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04 after that double-click  stopped working.

I already tried install/reinstall

Using `gnome-tweak-tool` I changed option to "area" and rebooted.

I tried reinstalling `xserver-xorg`.

I can go inside catalog by touchpad when I click about 10 times. With the mouse it doesn't work at all.

I have updated `libinput`.

In the conf file I have these values:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Driver "libinput"
  Option "Tapping" "True"
  Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"
EndSection
```

How can I solve this? I would be grateful for help!